# Assigning a created value to from one model to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@userc= User.create(:uname => params[:veliuname], :upass => params[:veliupass], :utype => 4, :isenabled=>true, :name=>params[:veliname], :surname => params[:velisurname], :mobiletel=>params[:velimobtel], :email=>params[:veliemail], :org_id => session[:user].org_id)

@pcurator = Pcurator.create(:user_id=>@userc.id , :address => params[:veliadrs], :city=>params[:velicity], :scity=>params[:veliscity], :othertel=>params[:velistatictel])
```

Here i am trying to create users, and then assign profiles to them. The problem is after creating user i am trying to assign that users id to pcurators user_id value. But it is not working and pcurator always have null as user_id in my database.

Any ideas how i can accomplish this? Or is there better Rails Way of doing this stuff?

Comment: by the way, it is happening in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@userc` is not yet pointing to an ActiveRecord record. You might try doing `@userc.reload!` to load the saved record. Anyhow, you can easily accomplish this without all this using complex forms. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1), [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3) are tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I dont find any problem with your code unless there is any validation on User model so that when you do User.create(...), the record is not getting saved. Otherwise User.create(..) should create a record in the db and the 'userc' should have an id.

Comment: Nope, user is saving itself to database, but its id stays null

Answer (score 0):

Another magical moment from rails and ruby, it started working without any change. I am starting to hate from this development environment